# Hide AJAX Button when disabled WooCommerce 2.6

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Before the WooCommerce 2.6 update, I used CSS to hide the Add to Cart button on the "single product" page when it is in the disabled state due to the product being out of stock. Now that WooCommerce made all of their cart functionality Ajax, that no longer works. The button is still visible.

I have confirmed that the CSS selectors I'm using for the button still work when I remove the ":disabled" selector.

I'm assuming I have to use JavaScript, which I am not well-versed in.

Comment: What is the markup of the button when it is in the disabled state?  Including classes, etc.

Comment: @Cass You can also try an other way, customizing related template *([once in your active theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/))*: `woocommerce>single-product>add-to-cart>simple.php` *(or some others depending of your products type)*. You also could use related hooks… Changing native core javascript/ajax behavior, is going to be complicated, I think. Don't forget that you have also some woocommerce settings regarding add to cart for products…